# using multiple "root to" with 2 devise models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have 2 devise models which is fine as they capture different values and i felt separating them was the best solution instead of using roles.

That being said, I am trying to root to different views. Here is my routes file:

```
devise_for :patients, controllers: {
        sessions: 'patients/sessions',
        registrations: 'patients/registrations'
      }

  as :patient do
    authenticated  do
      root to: 'dashboard#patient'
    end

    unauthenticated do
      root to: 'shared#home', as: 'unauthenticated_root'
    end
  end

  devise_for :pharmacists, controllers: {
        sessions: 'pharmacists/sessions',
        registrations: 'pharmacists/registrations'
      }

  as :pharmacist do
    authenticated  do
      root to: 'dashboard#pharmacist'
    end

    unauthenticated do
      root to: 'shared#home', as: 'unauthenticated_root'
    end
  end
```

This is the error message:

```
Invalid route name, already in use: 'root' 
You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, 
or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the 
same naming.
```

What would be the best way to alleviate this issue ?

Comment: Well, your routes have to be REST full, which also implies they are stateless (meaning they have to work regardless of being a authenticated patient or an unauthenticated), the only thing you can control is their behaviour in your controllers. Or in other words it is ok to have a root to "patient" and another to "pharmacist" (host/patient and host/pharmacist) but you can not expect any of those paths to know about authentication. I know this does not answer your question, but I think you are looking at it the wrong way.

Comment: Try using namespaces or scopes instead of `authenticated do` - `scope :authenticated do`. That would make your url look something like "host/pharmacist/authenticated... Problem is, that level of "nesting" is a little ugly

Comment: Do you mind giving me a more concrete example or a link to one? I am a bit confused by your response

Comment: I am really sorry I confused you even more, but I have never seen `authenticated do` syntax, so I kinda just tried to give you a general idea of what's wrong.What I was trying to say is, your routes.rb file seems to make a url which would look like "GET www.host/patient" with two different meanings (authenticated patient and unauthenticated). How does your server know which one of the the two "GET www.host/patient" you want to speak to, before evaluating your session? It can't, that's why this can not work, unless devise provides something I don't know here.

Comment: authenticated and unauthenticated are part of devise ... devise_scope is the same as "as". If i remove 1 of the as clauses it works. Ideally i just need it to route the patient to their dashboard and the pharmacist to theres after log in

Comment: I guess I can't help then :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue stems from the fact that i was not using "as:" on the actual roots so they end up having the same endpoints. after fixing this issue the correct code looks like this:

```
devise_for :patients, controllers: {
        sessions: 'patients/sessions',
        registrations: 'patients/registrations'
      }

  devise_scope :patient do
    authenticated  do
      root to: 'dashboard#patient', as: 'authenticated_patient_root'
    end

    unauthenticated do
      root to: 'shared#home', as: 'unauthenticated_patient_root'
    end
  end

  devise_for :pharmacists, controllers: {
        sessions: 'pharmacists/sessions',
        registrations: 'pharamacists/registrations'
      }

  devise_scope :pharmacist do
    authenticated  do
      root to: 'dashboard#pharmacist', as: 'authenticated_pharmacist_root'
    end

    unauthenticated do
      root to: 'shared#home', as: 'unauthenticated_pharmacist_root'
    end
  end
```

Comment: humm... I would be really sad if what I said did not even hint you what the problem was :P

Comment: it dawned on me when i was reading through because i thought to myself how can this not work. Then i looked at the way i wrote the as on the unauthenticated root and then thought to myself how can both "as" have the same path. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve the same thing using the below hacks without the `devise_scope`

```
authenticated :patient do
  root to: "patients#show", as: :authenticated_patient
end

authenticated :pharmacist  do
  root "pharmacists#index", as: :authenticated_pharmacist
end

unauthenticated  do
  root "pages#home", as: :unauthenticated_user
end
```